# Can't open HTTP links in iOS due to security issue

Tags: ios, json, xcode, swift, app-transport-security

[image: The solution to the problem but still getting the error]

App Transport Security has blocked a cleartext HTTP (http://) resource load since it is insecure. Temporary exceptions can be configured via your app's Info.plist file.

I have tried the solution  on the picture but still getting the error

```
   import UIKit

   class ViewController: UIViewController {


   lazy var data = NSMutableData()


    override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.



    let url = NSURL(string: "http://android.goidx.com/search")
    let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
    let task = session.dataTaskWithURL(url!, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) -> Void in
        if error != nil {
            print(error)
            } else {
            do {
                let jsonResult = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers) as!  NSDictionary
                // print(jsonResult)

                print(jsonResult[0])
            } catch {
                print("my error")
            }
        }

    })

    task.resume()





}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
  }




 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your plist file should look like this:
[image]
And note that your code crashes the app, because you are casting to a dictionary where it should be an array:

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.



        let url = NSURL(string: "http://android.goidx.com/search")
        let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
        let task = session.dataTaskWithURL(url!, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) -> Void in
            if error != nil {
                print(error)
            } else {
                do {
                    let jsonResult = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers) as!  NSArray
                    // print(jsonResult)

                    print(jsonResult[0])
                } catch {
                    print("my error")
                }
            }

        })

        task.resume()





    }
```

All should then work - it does for me.

Comment: it working Thanks . i have last question  since my json file is presented as dictionary on that link . Should i store as nsarray as you said our nsdictionary

Comment: it is an array that is returned and given your `print(jsonResult[0])` I'm guessing that you were expecting that. The object at `jsonResult[0]` is a dictionary however.